# Custom view code for a line that 'grows' from a specified start point to a specified end point

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to draw  a line using Canvas API which starts from a specified start point and 'grows' horizontally until it reaches a specified end point.
Can anybody provide code for that?
Thanks!

Comment: Drawing a line is easy-  just use canvas.drawLine.

The growth behavior-  that will require you to use an Animation and animate the end point of the line from the starting position to the ending position.  Look into ValueAnimators and animate the end point.  Then the redraw should draw the line to the position whenever the animator fires.

Comment: @GabeSechan, trying, thanks!

Comment: @GabeSechan, any idea how I can animate growth of line in jetpack compose?

Comment: Its not a Compose thing.  You're going to need a custom view if you're making Canvas calls.  Just put the custom view in your Compose code, and then the animation would happen inside that custom view.